# barbed wire parenthesis in LaTeX

Tags: latex, mathematical-typesetting

How to typeset in LaTex barbed wire brackets as used to denote paramorphism in the paper "Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12895/overlay-symbol-with-another) I was able to come up with:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\lbarb}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hss(\hss\cr\{}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rbarb}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hss)\hss\cr\}}}}
```